# How can show only those user who is not linked with project in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to show only those developers who are not linked with project but it always show one developer who is already linked

ProjectDeveloper is model which have project and developer id
User have a column user type which type is enum who contain developer manager and qa

controller

```
 def index

    @users = User.where(user_type: 'Developer')
    @project_developer = ProjectsDeveloper.where.not(id: @users.ids)
    project_id = params['project_id'].to_i
    @project_id = Project.find(project_id)
 end
```

html.erb

```
<% @project_developer.each do |user| %>
   <h3><%=user.developer_id %></h3>

   <%=button_to 'Assign' , projects_developer_index_path({project_id: @project_id.id, developer_id: user.id}),
         method: :post %><br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
def index
    @project = Project.find(params['project_id'].to_i)
    @project_developer = project.projects_developers.pluck(:developer_id)
    @users = User.where(user_type: 'Developer').where.not(id: @project_developer)
 end
```

And in view use @users instance to display developers.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <h3><%=user.id %></h3>

   <%=button_to 'Assign' , projects_developer_index_path({project_id: @project_id.id, developer_id: user.id}),
         method: :post %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: then how can i show all developer who linked with this project

Comment: Just remove `.not` from query and it will return linked developer
 @developers = User.where(user_type: 'Developer').where(id: @project_developer)